# Extern struct in C

Tags: c, extern, f2c

I have a C file generated with f2c (Fortran to C translator) that contains the following C structure:

```
struct {
    real rez, pi, st;
} const_;
```

How can I declare this `const_` variable as an external in another .c file without modifying the one generated by f2c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In another file.

```
extern struct {
    real rez, pi, st;
} const_;
```